# Can I have a TableLayout in an AppWidget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

LinearLayout just works fine in an AppWidget. However, when I change the layout's xml to a TableLayout, I am unable to get the widget working :(.

Can anyone point me to a sample? [could not find anything on the web]

-Sri

Answer (score 2):

`AppWidget`s use [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) to implement their interface and only Views with the [`RemoteViews.RemoteView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.RemoteView.html) annotation can be used. This is the [list of the Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) in the android.widget package that have this annotation:

- AbsoluteLayout
- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- FrameLayout
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- LinearLayout
- ProgressBar
- RelativeLayout
- TextView
- ViewFlipper

Comment: Thanks for your time :-). 

I was able to get a what I wanted through the RelativeLayout. 

-Sri